# Error deploying to App Engine

Tags: eclipse, google-app-engine, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

I have a GWT application that makes extensive use of code splitting and internationalization and therefore generates many separate files (1000+).  I want to deploy my GWT app to App Engine using Google Plugin for Eclipse, but when I try I get the following error on the eclipse console:

```
Deploying:
    Uploading 1187 files.
     on backend null.
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server

Debugging information may be found in C:\Users\Chania\AppData\Local\Temp\appengine-deploy3688011582342735160.log

Contents of appengine-deploy3688011582342735160.log:
Unable to update:
java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$6.run(HttpURLConnection.java:1491)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getChainedException(HttpURLConnection.java:1485)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1139)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:277)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send(AbstractServerConnection.java:245)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.post(AbstractServerConnection.java:211)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.send(AppVersionUpload.java:611)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.access$300(AppVersionUpload.java:33)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload$UploadBatcher.addToBatch(AppVersionUpload.java:910)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.uploadFile(AppVersionUpload.java:510)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppVersionUpload.doUpload(AppVersionUpload.java:129)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.doUpdate(AppAdminImpl.java:328)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AppAdminImpl.update(AppAdminImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.proxy.AppEngineBridgeImpl.deploy(AppEngineBridgeImpl.java:400)
    at com.google.appengine.eclipse.core.deploy.DeployProjectJob.runInWorkspace(DeployProjectJob.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:54)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:578)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(HttpURLConnection.java:590)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1193)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:234)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.connect(AbstractServerConnection.java:131)
    at com.google.appengine.tools.admin.AbstractServerConnection.send1(AbstractServerConnection.java:275)
    ... 13 more
```

Does anyone have any clue as to what might have gone south?

Comment: it has almost been a month since my last successful deployment

Answer (score 2):

[UnzipperServlet](https://github.com/gvaish/gae-utils) can be used to zip all static files before they are uploaded. So instead of uploading hundreds of static files you upload a single zip-file.

The UnzipperServlet was specifically created to take care of the 'too many files' issue at GAE.

**edit:** It seems like the file limit has been raised from 1000 to 3000 files. So you can probably ignore my 'solution'.